# WPF OnBeforeParentSizeChanging OnAfterParentSizeChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, events, controls

i'm developing an Custom Control where i need to render a picture in the background.
while the user is resizing the window i need to stop the rendering and start it when the user is ready.

actually what i whould need is a OnBeforeParentSizeChanging and OnAfterParentSizeChanged event or something like this.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd hook into Win32 WndProc events `WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE` and `WM_EXITSIZEMOVE`:

```
public class ResizeWindow : Window
{
    public ResizeWindow()
    {
        this.Loaded += ResizeWindow_Loaded;
    }

    void ResizeWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        HwndSource source = HwndSource.FromHwnd(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle);
        source.AddHook(new HwndSourceHook(WndProc));
    }

    public event EventHandler Resizing;
    public event EventHandler Resized;

    private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
    {
        const int WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE = 0x0231;
        const int WM_EXITSIZEMOVE = 0x0232;

        if (msg == WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE)
        {
            if(Resizing != null)
            {
                Resizing(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
        else if (msg == WM_EXITSIZEMOVE)
        {
            if (Resized != null)
            {
                Resized(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }

        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }
}
```

}

Here's how you would go about using it:

```
public partial class MainWindow : ResizeWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.Resized += MainWindow_Resized;
        this.Resizing += MainWindow_Resizing;

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void MainWindow_Resizing(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Resizing!");
    }

    void MainWindow_Resized(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Resized!");
    }
}
```

In your particular case, you would first have to change the base class on the parent window and expose the `Resizing` and `Resized` to the control.

Comment: as it is a Control i whould like not to force the user to make changes on he's mainWindow in order to support the control itself.... but it looks like a greate solution!